# log model , per capita variabel?

Tags: model, logarithm

I have a question regarding statistics interpretation . As far as I know when I have two variables I can interpret the results as following: 
Y and X -- a one unit increase in X would lead to a β
β increase/decrease in Y

Log Y and Log X -- a 1% increase in X would lead to a β
β% increase/decrease in Y

Log Y and X -- a one unit increase in X would lead to a β∗100
β∗100% increase/decrease in Y

Y and Log X -- a 1% increase in X would lead to a β/100
β/100 increase/decrease in Y

My question is how can interpret the following:
 1. log(y) = 956*(per_capita_x)+e 
2. per_capita(y) = -7,56*(per_capita_x)+e

Should I multiply 956*100 since y is log ? in (1)
Do I need to multiply -7,56 or not since y is per capita and not logged(in 2)